# Java: Load image from file, edit and add to JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I want to load an image from my computer into 2D Graphics so that I can edit it afterwards and then I want to add it to `JPanel`. If you need to see my project I can send it to you.

```
void loadImage()
{

    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Please choose a file:", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.show();
    if (fd.getFile() != null)
    {
        File fil = new File(fd.getDirectory(), fd.getFile());
        strDirectory = fd.getDirectory();
        strFileType = fd.getFile();
        mainImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fil.toString()));
        getFileList(strDirectory);
        checkFileType(strFileType);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

To load your image into the memory, you can use `ImageIO.read(File)`. To edit it afterwards, obtain a Graphics2D instance from it by calling `createGraphics()`:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(yourFile);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
// Draw here on the graphics
g.dispose();
```

You can even turn on anti-alias by setting a RenderingHint before drawing:

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                   RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIASING_ON);
```

Then, to add it to a JPanel, create your custom JComponent and add an instance of that component to your JPanel:

```
public class JImageComponent extends JComponent
{
    private BufferedImage img;

    public JImageComponent(BufferedImage bi)
    {
        img = bi;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImg(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

please read this tutorials about [Icon in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) and your Image/ImageIcon would by placed to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), this way eliminated all troubles came from paint/paintComponents ...

Answer (score 1):

For image loading you should use `ImageIO` object with method `read(File file)` [see docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29). Then you will get `BufferedImage` instance of which you can make your changes through `Graphics2D` instance which you'll obtain by calling `createGraphics()` on the image instance [see docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29). Last thing, override method `paintComponent()` from `JPanel` or better `JComponent` [see docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) and there you can draw your image on `Graphics` instance which you'll get as parameter in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method by calling `drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)` [see docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) where `ImageObserver` set to `null`.

Comment: Do not override `paint(...)`, instead override `paintComponent(...)`.