# Load an image into a JPanel in an applet

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, jfilechooser

base on this thread :[Java: Load image from file, edit and add to JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795023/java-load-image-from-file-edit-and-add-to-jpanel)
i tried to load na image into a JPanel but its not painting it,so here s the deal, as suggested i have created a new class file named JImageComponent which extends from a JComponent, which looks like this :

```
package in.co.sneh;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
private BufferedImage img;
    public class JImageComponent  extends JComponent
{
    public JImageComponent (BufferedImage bi)
{
    img = bi;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}
}
```

then in the applet form class ,when i click on the loadPicture Button, the action performed looks like this :

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
   int retVal = chooser.showDialog(AppletForm.this, "Attach");
    if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        picFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {

            image = ImageIO.read(picFile);
            JImageComponent jcomp = new JImageComponent(image);
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            jcomp.paintComponents(g);
            // Draw here on the graphics
            //g.dispose();
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            jPanel6.add(jcomp);
            System.out.println("Testing" + picFile);



        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

to me everything is in place however the image is not showing when in the file explorer  choose the image, can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance,
Romulo Romero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding a new component to the container, you need to call

```
jPanel6.revalidate();
jPanel6.repaint();
```

Also applets cannot load resources from the local file system unless they are *signed*.

Note: 
While having a a single `JImageComponent` would be better, `JLabel` components already offer the functionality of switching images by using [setIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29).

Comment: Hi Reimeus first of all,
thanks a lot for replying and sorry for the delay,and yeah i decided to work with label and setting an image icon, and it Works like a charm :D
thanks again for replying i really appreciate it,everything is running as expected now :D!!
kind regards,
Romulo Romero

Comment: Stupid redundancy of "and"

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple applet code that helps u to edit images....

```
you can try it

/*Arpana*/

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ConvolveApp extends JFrame {
  CPanel displayPanel;

  JButton sharpenButton, blurringButton, edButton, resetButton;

  public ConvolveApp() {
    super();
    Container container = getContentPane();

    displayPanel = new CPanel();
    container.add(displayPanel);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    panel
        .setBorder(new TitledBorder(
            "Click a Button to Perform the Associated Operation and Reset..."));

    sharpenButton = new JButton("Sharpen");
    sharpenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    blurringButton = new JButton("Blur");
    blurringButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    edButton = new JButton("Edge Detect");
    edButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel.add(sharpenButton);
    panel.add(blurringButton);
    panel.add(edButton);
    panel.add(resetButton);

    container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
     //setSize(100,100);
    setSize(displayPanel.getWidth()+50, displayPanel.getHeight() );
    setVisible(true); 
  }
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new ConvolveApp();
  }

  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

      if (button.equals(sharpenButton)) {
        displayPanel.sharpen();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(blurringButton)) {
        displayPanel.blur();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(edButton)) {
        displayPanel.edgeDetect();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(resetButton)) {
        displayPanel.reset();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      }
    }
  }
}

class CPanel extends JLabel {
  Image displayImage;

  BufferedImage biSrc;

  BufferedImage biDest; // Destination image is mandetory.

  BufferedImage bi; // Only an additional reference.

  Graphics2D big;

  CPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.black);
    loadImage();
    setSize(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getWidth(this)); 
    createBufferedImages();
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void loadImage() {
    displayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Desert.jpg");
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    mt.addImage(displayImage, 1);
    try {
      mt.waitForAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception while loading.");
    }
    if (displayImage.getWidth(this) == -1) {
      System.out.println("No jpg file");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public void createBufferedImages() {
    biSrc = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    big = biSrc.createGraphics();
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);

    biDest = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  }

  public void sharpen() {
    float data[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 9.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void blur() {
    float data[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f,
        0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

    public void edgeDetect() {
    float data[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f };

    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);

    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void reset() {
    big.setColor(Color.black);
    big.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this));
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    paintComponent(g);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```